# Cache to Stop and Start Movement in an Animation?

Tags: animation, keyframes, smoke-simulation, cloth-simulation, cache

So I am working on an animation that is about 4 minutes long and various elements that use physics in the scene come in and out of shot, namely fire and moving cloth. I am wondering if there is an efficient way to only cache the frames that these items are visible? Doing so would save considerable render time.
I can easily make separate cache files that would be keyed to the desired frames but is there any way to keyframe which cache it should use? I can only select one at a time and I cannot find a way to switch what is selected via the timeline/dope sheet.

Also, I fear I am overlooking an easier solution but at this moment I cannot figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!